# operator << overload

Tags: c++, namespaces, using, std, operator-keyword

```
//using namespace std;

using std::ifstream;

using std::ofstream;

using std::cout;

class Dog
{

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Dog&);

    public:
        char* name;
        char* breed;
        char* gender;

        Dog();
        ~Dog();

};
```

im trying to overload the << operator. I'm also trying to practice good coding. But my code wont compile unless i uncomment the using namespace std. i keep getting this error and i dont know. im using g++ compiler.

```
Dog.h:20: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘ostream’ with no type
Dog.h:20: error: ‘ostream’ is neither function nor member function; cannot be declared friend. if i add line using std::cout; then i get this error.
Dog.h:21: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘ostream’ with no type.
```

Can somebody tell me the correct way to overload the << operator with out using namespace std;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `using std::ofstream` instead of `using std::ostream`, so it doesn't know what `ostream` is.

You also need to include `<ostream>`.

Really, though, there's no reason to use `using anything`; you should just qualify the names with the namespace (*especially* if this is a header file, to avoid polluting the global namespace of other files):

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Dog&);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `using` keyword just means to let you access something without prefixing it with its namespace.  In orther words, `using std::ofstream;` just says to let you access `std::ofstream` as `ofstream`.

You also seem to need a `#include <iostream>`; that's why the compiler doesn't know what `ostream` is.  Put that in, change the friend declaration to `friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Dog&);`, and get rid of all the `using` stuff, since it's bad form to put `using` in a header, and you should be okay.