# C++ overloading operator << causing me nightmares

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

i viewed all other threads related to my problem, such as:

[Overloading the << operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436393/overloading-the-operator)

[operator << overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695753/operator-overload)

and i feel im so close to solve my problem, but no success. i hope you guys can assist.

i have the following example code, and i need to make him compile:

```
auto fan3 = std::make_shared<Fan>(3,"Not Connected");

//.... lots of code

std::cout << "User: " << *fan3 << " not connected" << std::endl;
```

i was getting the error "Invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream >' and 'mtm::Fan')", so i figured i need to implement the << operator.

i tried to put the following in fan.h:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Fan& fan);
```

but im getting "undefined symbols". putting it outside of the class (without 'friend' ofcourse) results in same error.

i guess there is something i dont quite understand about this kind of behaviour - i did implemnet other operator overloading, but << is just giving me troubles so far.

please, explain to me what i am missing and how to resolve this issue. 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need to actually implement the operator.

Comment: In addition to what @juanchopanza says, you should probably make the operator take `const Fan&` instead of `Fan&`, so that it can be used to output temporaries.

Comment: @juanchopanza i tried to implement the operator but im getting the same error. as if it doenst 'see' the implementation

Comment: Basing on your comments on answers you should provide more of your code (with exactly same file division) and show us error you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a free function like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fan& fan);
```

And then implement it, like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fan& fan)
{
    return os << fan.whatever;
}
```

This should be done in the namespace of your class if your class is in a namespace, but not within the class itself.

Comment: You can also do it within the class, `friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Fan const& object ) { /*...*/ }`.  (This is, in fact, a common idiom.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: it may be common in some codebases, but personally I prefer not to have friends unless absolutely necessary (and it very rarely is necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. do i need to add a conversion between Fan and const Fan? edit: still undefined symbol.

Comment: @JohnZwinck when you say 'free function', you need in the fan.h but not inside the class. and implementation goes in the cpp? it just seems as it doesnt 'find' the implementation.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's a question of convention.  In this case, it's often used (especially in templates) so that the implementation of `operator<<` can be inline in the class definition (and thus found with ADL), even in cases where it doesn't require access to the private parts.  One can consider it simply as a way of writing a member function which doesn't have the implied first argument the class type.

Comment: @JamesKanze: ADL works if it's in the class namespace without being in the class.  If you like having friends, you can, but it isn't needed for ADL or any other reason apart from access to privates which is rarely needed for a normal ostream operator.

Comment: @Zephyer: yes, I mean declared at global or namespace scope in the header and defined in the .cpp file.  A "free function" is by contrast to a "member function."

Comment: @JohnZwinck But it's much cleaner to treat it as a member function (whether or not it needs access to private variables).  I don't understand your attitude with regards to `friend`; `friend` is an important mechanism to improve encapsulation, and encapsulation is important if you want the software to be maintainable.

Comment: I solved this in the help of this post mainly. i had to add the namespace at the .cpp. so much time wasted on this! thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an implementation of the function, you get undefined symbol error because there is no implementation of the declaration. You need something like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Fan const& fan) {
                                                ^^^ add this also to 
                                                    bind to temporaries
    /* and output what is needed, i.e name of the Fan if it exists */
    return os << fan.name;
}
```

You must assure this function is declared and defined in correct **namespaces**.

---

### friend keyword

this is needed only if you want to output a private member of the class

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this doesnt solve the problem though. what else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

class Fan {
    public:
        int value;
    Fan (int _v):value(_v){};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fan& fan)
{
    return os << fan.value;
}

int main(void){
    Fan *f = new Fan(5);
    std::cout << "val: " << *f << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

this is an example that works